# Getting a warning when updating a column using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do some cleanup on the data I receive.

The code is as follow:

```py
import pandas as pd

def cleanup(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Remove entries from the IT dept
    mask = (df['dept'] != 'IT')
    df = df[mask]

    # Rename the dept from marketing to comms for the remaining rows
    mask = df['dept'] == 'marketing'
    df.loc[mask, 'dept'] = "comms"
    # The warning occurs here...

    # Rename the dept from accounting to finance for the remaining rows
    mask = df['dept'] == 'accounting'
    df.loc[mask, 'dept'] = 'finance'

    return df

data = [[1,"marketing"],[2,"accounting"],[3,"marketing"],[4,"IT"],[5,"IT"],[6,"board"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'dept'])
df=cleanup(df)
```

I get the following warning:

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:480: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>   self.obj[item] = s

I'm a bit worried about this warning since the returned data *are correct* and the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) does not seem to apply in this case.

Is there anything wrong with my code?
Or can I safely ignore the warning?

Comment: What about  `df = df[mask].copy()` so you are not working with a slice anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it. Your `df` is a slice of another frame by `df=df[mask]`. Try to update the original frame, not the slice:

```
def cleanup(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Remove entries from the IT dept
    mask1 = (df['dept'] != 'IT')

    # Rename the dept from marketing to comms for the remaining rows
    mask2 = df['dept'] == 'marketing'
    df.loc[mask1 & mask2, 'dept'] = "comms"
    # The warning occurs here...

    # Rename the dept from accounting to finance for the remaining rows
    mask2 = df['dept'] == 'accounting'
    df.loc[mask1&mask2, 'dept'] = 'finance'

    return df

data = [[1,"marketing"],[2,"accounting"],[3,"marketing"],[4,"IT"],[5,"IT"],[6,"board"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'dept'])
df=cleanup(df)
```

The modified function returns the new `df` **with** `IT` values in `dept`. If, in fact, you don't want these records, you can make a copy and update on that:

```
def cleanup(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Remove entries from the IT dept
    mask = (df['dept'] != 'IT')

    # we copy the data frame here so it's no longer a slice
    df = df[mask].copy()  

    # Rename the dept from marketing to comms for the remaining rows
    mask = df['dept'] == 'marketing'
    df.loc[mask, 'dept'] = "comms"
    # The warning occurs here...

    # Rename the dept from accounting to finance for the remaining rows
    mask = df['dept'] == 'accounting'
    df.loc[mask, 'dept'] = 'finance'

    return df
```